# Which folders in an Eclipse Android project do I need to back up in SVN?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

It's all in the title really: I don't want to include folders that are generated by Eclipse - I just want to know what's the minimum I need to include in my SVN backup.

I'm guessing AndroidManifest.xml, src, assets (empty in my case) and res. What about libs, which contains android-support-v4.jar? Anything else?

My SVN is external to eclipse as I have several projects in different languages and TortoiseSVN itself, which I use, is installed on my PC. So I don't want to use any integrated plug-in.

Thanks.

PS: I checked other similar questions/answers but none really answered this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, SVN is not a backup, it's version control. Don't use it as a backup.

Second, there is no difference if you use the integrated plugin, the command line client or some UI tool.

Finally, what you don't want to put in VC are generally generated files and files specific to your workspace (if multiple people are working on the code). For Android projects, generated files include the `bin/` and `gen/` directories. You might want to put `libs/` in VC for convenience, but it is not strictly necessary, since you can get the libraries from somewhere else. On the other hand putting them in VC guarantees that everyone is using the same version.     Workspace-specific files are Eclipse's `.settings/`, `.metadata`, etc. It is also advisable to  keep your project code and the Eclipse workspace directory separate, so that you can recover easily when Eclipse messes up.

So, exclude the above and put everything else in VC.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Yes, I used the term "backup" loosely. It's only me working on the code, so I don't have to consider multiple people.